# stripe connect Error of Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\Authentication' with message 'The provided key 'sk_test_' does not have access to account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_someString");
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
  array(
    "amount" => 5000, // amount in cents
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "Example charge",
    "application_fee" => 123 // amount in cents
  ),
  array("stripe_account" => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID)
);

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined

}
catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
    // Network problem, perhaps try again.
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
    // You screwed up in your programming. Shouldn't happen!
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Api $e) {
    // Stripe's servers are down!
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // Card was declined.
}
```

Everything I have done so far:
Create a custom form add all the necessary coding provided by stripe
add the latest php stripe dependency
Add the localhost url to my stripe connect 
The problem is after I connect by clicking the connect with stripe button 
Then use the demo card and post a request such error comes back an also no 
charge occur. In the logs I see the post but no Parsed Request Query Parameters. Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: I have also tried print_r($_POST) but only the token am seeing not seeing no way to grab the account ID from the URL